# Identifying user's country in a Chromecast receiver app?

Tags: geolocation, chromecast, ip-geolocation

Is there a way to identify a user's country in a Chromecast receiver app?
I don't see any mention about a Location API in the cast documentation.
Would the HTML Geolocation API work inside a TV? Will it ask for permission?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Cast Documentation](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/web_receiver), a Web Receiver application is an HTML5/JavaScript application. You should be able to make an HTTP GET request to an IP Geolocation API such as the one provided by [Ipregistry](https://ipregistry.co).

Here is a code sample using `XMLHttpRequest`:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
        var json = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        console.log('Your country is ' + json['location']['country']['name']);
    }
};
request.open('GET', 'https://api.ipregistry.co/?key=tryout', true);
request.send(null);
```

and another using `fetch`:

```
fetch('https://api.ipregistry.co/?key=tryout')
    .then(function (response) {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(function (json) {
        console.log('Your country is ' + json['location']['country']['name']);
    });
```

The request that is sent to the IP Geolocation API exposes the public user IP address. This IP address is then used to guess the user country. Usually, country accuracy from IP addresses is very good.